# Understanding execution of recursion in tree traversal

Tags: recursion, tree, tree-traversal

I am having problem understanding the recursion execution in tree traversal.

```
 void travel (Node *tree)
 { 
     if(tree!=NULL)
     {
         printf("%d ",tree->info); 
         travel(tree->left);
         travel(tree->right);
      }
 }
```

Here can you explain

```
      1
   2     3
 4     5   6
```

Output: 1 2 4 3 5 6

What happens after reaching 4. Does how does the compiler ignore travel(tree->left) and how does it goes back till 1 and reaches 3.

My exact question is how does the function call travel(tree->left) gets ignored ?

Answer (score 0):

It's all about returning from the function.

```
     void travel (Node *tree)
 { 
     if(tree!=NULL)
     {
         printf("%d ",tree->info); 
         travel(tree->left);
         travel(tree->right);
      }
 }


      1
   2     3
 4     5   6
```

In the above function it takes left path as along as there is a child to go. If it finds no left child then tries right child. If no right child found then returns the function. Up until we reach node "4"  we haven't yet processed a single return from the function. Once we are at 4 we see there is no more left child is left so we try right child but there is no right child as well. So we return the function to from where we had been called. That happens to be 2. So we will continue from where we had left at 2. At 2 we had taken the left path by invoking the `travel(tree->left);` instruction and now that we return from this instruction we will now continue with the next instruction which is `travel(tree->right);` alas there is no right child so we return the function from where we had started.. which happens to be node 1 at line `travel(tree->right);` now it's turn for the next line `travel(tree->right);` hence we arrive to 3.

I hope you could follow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. ""Once we are at 4 we see there is no more left child is left so we try right child but there is no right child as well. "" Here how does the COMPILER get to know about no child being there, as the left and right node is just an function parameter isnt it ??? I mean the condition to check if there right or left child is absent, so how it happens ?

Comment: Hi in this C code `tree` is a pointer to a struct (say like a constructor function in JS) and it's left and right properties are also pointers in the same fashion. You just pass this pointer to the `travel` function like `travel(tree->right)` to process the node that the passed argument points at. In this case processing the node means the instruction `printf("%d ",tree->info);`. Once your processing finishes you make another call to the same travel function within itself with the next node passed as an argument. More on C pointers http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/structs/arrow.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suppose that you know when the program enter in a function, it does not exit it until it ends. After that lets go to analyze the code and its execution.

I assume that you are working with pointer due to the NULL condition in the if statement, and each element has two pointer to the left and right child, that can be null as well.

First of all your function analyzes the first element (Number 1) and check if is null, as it is not, enter in the if statement, prints its value and goes to its left child, repeat the process, check if 4 is null, as it is not, enter in the if statement prints its value and goes to its left child, and this is were recursive magic happens, when the child of the element 4 is null, the function returns and do not continue recursive. After that, it returns to the level of the number 4 element, and check right child, as it is null returns to number 1 level, and know check number 1 right child and continue as always.

You must imagine recursive like levels and when you finish in one returns to the previous, and continue the normal execution, until there are not more recursive.

I hope it helps you and sorry for my English if you do not understand anything.

Comment: Thanls for the reply ""when the child of the element 4 is null, the function returns and do not continue recursive"".  Can you explain on this point alone.       Where is the check made about the left child is null or not ???

Comment: First of all the compiler do not check that. It happens in runtime. The element 4 has two pointer: leftChild and rightChild even if they are null.

When the function is called with the leftChild it checks if is null, and as element 4 has not children it is null, so it comes back to level 4 and checks right child and repeats. Once it has check all its children the functions exit the if statement and goes up to level 2 and repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So if instead of recursion assume it is just a function call. Like func(tree->left). So if this is called after reaching 4 , the function get the value NULL in parameter and starts execution isn't it ??? Thats a normal way of execution. So how does recursion has a privilege of checking the null in runtime.

Comment: When it get number 4 left child and checks that it is null, it does not enter in the if statement and goes back to number 4 level, then it checks right child, and checks again if it is null. Once it finish with number 4 children it goes up  to number 2 level and continue the execution. You must image it like something that goes deeper until the exit condition (In this case when a child is null) comes true, in that moment it goes up and tries another path repeating the process until there is no more possible path.